# Properties of a derivative of a function $f(x)$ expressed as a function of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider a differentiable function $f(x)$ and let $u(f(x)) = f'(x)$.
Normally we solve for $u$ as a function of $x$, but we can also express it as a function of $f$.
Some examples:

If $f(x) = e^{-x}$, then $f'(x) = -e^{-x} = - f(x)$, hence $u(f) = -f$.

If $f(x) = x^{-1}$, then $f'(x) = -x^{-2} = -(x^{-1})^2 = -f(x)^2$, so $u(f) = -f^2$.

If $f(x) = \tan(x)$, then $f'(x) = \sec^2(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x) = 1 + f(x)^2$, thus $u(f) = 1 + f^2$.

These show up in elementary differential equations like $\frac{dy}{dx} = -y$.

My first question is if it is always possible to express $u$ solely in terms of $f$ and not $x$.
Intuitively, it seems to be so, for while the mapping from $\ln(x)$ to $x^{-1}$ or $\sin(x)$ to $\cos(x)$
may not be easily expressible in terms of elementary functions,
it is certainly a well-defined function wherever $f'(x)$ is defined,
although the existence of everywhere continuous, nowhere differentiable functions
means $u$ does not always exist.
Naturally, I welcome any counter-example which forces $u$ to depend on $x$ and not $f$ only.

Secondly, when, if ever, does $u$ have the same form as $f$? That is, for what function $f(x)$ does $u(t) = f(t)$?
(Using $t$ instead of $x$ to avoid confusion.)
Is this function unique, up to a constant?

I feel that this ought to have come up in an elementary analysis or differential equations course,
but I don't recall it doing so. I'd especially be glad to see a reference to an in-depth discussion in a textbook or a paper.
My own cursory searches have been fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, *almost* yes. If $\exists f^{-1}$, you can write $u(f(x))=f′(x)$ equivalently as $u(y)=f′(f^{-1}(y))$. Obviously, the *global* existence of $f^{-1}$ is false in general, but you have *local* existence near the points $c$ s.t. $f'(c)\ne 0$ (Inverse Function Theorem).

Now, think yourself in the second question.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed the inverse function the first time I look at this. As for the second part, I know that when $f(x)=c$ the case trivially holds since $u(f)=c$ as well, but I was hoping for a non-trivial case.